# Cycle of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a 1-dimensional scheme and it contains a cycle of curves $C_1,...,C_n$ that intersect at $x_1,...,x_n$. At this point I want to study $H^1(X,O_X)$ to find a closed subscheme of an algebraic surface with $h^1>n$, so I want to prove that $H^1(X,O_X)$ is nonzero and its dimension is at least n.

My approach: In order to do this I was thinking of constructing some short exact sequence (probably there is a canonical one in this case that I am missing) in order to deal with the n curves and their intersection points starting with $O_X\rightarrow \oplus O_{C_i}$.

Comment: The question is unclear. You have curves $C_i$. Where are the $x_i$s? For example, can you tell me what happens when n=2$, $n=3$?

Comment: Sorry, You are right. $x_i\in C_i\cap C_{i+1}$ and $x_n\in C_1\cap C_n$.

Comment: I think that we can reduce to the case X is actually the union of the curves and in that case we have $0\rightarrow O_X\rightarrow \oplus O_{C_i}\rightarrow \oplus k_{x_i} \rightarrow 0$ where $k_{x_i}$ are the skyscraeper sheaves at the points. With this we get a long exact sequence and we know $h^1(\oplus C_i)$ is the sum of the genus of the curves, so we are done unless the curves are all lines.